# unknown type name error with typedef struct and extern declaration - C language

Tags: c, struct, types

I would like to understand an error from my compiler in C language.

In a file application.h, I create a typedef struct :

```
typedef struct
{
    FLOAT64 CoefficientA1_F64;
    FLOAT64 CoefficientA2_F64;
    FLOAT64 CoefficientB0_F64;
    FLOAT64 CoefficientB1_F64;
    FLOAT64 CoefficientB2_F64;
    FLOAT32 OldOldRawValue_F32;
    FLOAT32 OldRawValue_F32;
    FLOAT32 RawValue_F32;
    FLOAT32 OldOldFilteredValue_F32;
    FLOAT32 OldFilteredValue_F32;
    FLOAT32 FilteredValue_F32;
}ButterwothSecondOrderFilterParameter_str;
```

Then I create variable in another file temperature.c :

```
ButterwothSecondOrderFilterParameter_str TMP_TemperatureLowPassFilterParameter_STR;
```

Then I declare this new variable as extern in temperature.h to do the possibility to use it in another file :

```
extern ButterwothSecondOrderFilterParameter_str TMP_TemperatureLowPassFilterParameter_STR;
```

For a *.c file I only includes his related *.h file and if I need global variable from another *.h file I include it in the *.h file

For example temperature.c only includes temperature.h and to access to the typedef struct of application.h I include application.h in temperature.h.

For my *.h file I always encapsulate with a :

```
#ifndef xxxx
#define xxxx
#endif
```

And this is this last declaration which generates an error :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
unknown type name 'ButterwothSecondOrderFilterParameter_str'
```

I don't know where's my error.... ?

Comment: If you only include the `temperature.h` header file, and not the `application.h` header file, how will then the compiler know what the symbol `ButterwothSecondOrderFilterParameter_str` is?

Comment: `temperature.h` must include `application.h` for the type to be known. You should be able to include `temperature.h` (only) at the top of `temperature.c` and the file should compile (that makes the header self-contained).  At the moment, the file doesn't compile; the header isn't self-contained.  The header guards are used to ensure that the headers are idempotent; even if they are included several times, the effect is the same as including them once.

Comment: Rather than explaining with words, explain with code: Please provide [mcve]. Currently it's unclear where your problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Justly I included application.h in temperature.h. Then temperature.h is the only file included in temperature.c. I add that temperature.h is included in application.h too normally without consequence.

I tried to add application.h directly in temperature.c but I have the same error.

I tried to delete the extern declaration in temperature.h and it works.

So the type in unknown for temperature.h but not for temperature.c....I don't understand.